# Model rails calculate total price

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, sum

I am trying to calculate a total sum from an array of ids.
It works fine when I select only one `Servicio` but in an array it shows me this message:

```
    undefined method `+' for #<Servicio:0x9c14c5c>

Extracted source (around line #91):

88:         </div>
89:         <div class="large-3 columns">
90:           <strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:total) %>:</strong></dt>
91:           <%= @recibo.total %>
92:         </div>
93:       </div>
94:     </div>
```

This is my model Recibo

```
class Recibo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cajero, 
  :doctor_id, 
  :numero_recibo, 
  :paciente_id, 
  :total,
  :servicio_ids

  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :paciente
  has_many :atencions
  has_many :servicios, :through => :atencions

  def total
    servicio_by_id = Servicio.find(servicio_ids)
    total = servicio_by_id.sum.precio
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify which attribute of the `Servicio` should be used by the `sum` method since the `Servicio` class does not implement the `+` method itself.

Try this

```
total = servicio_by_id.sum(&:precio)
```

This will add up the value of each `Servicio`'s `precio` attribute.